# Best method to display graphics

Tags: android, graphics

So I'm making a simple game for Android and I'm trying to figure out which method of rendering I should use. I'm pretty new so simpler = better. The thing I'm trying to do is pretty simple: draw 2.5D (skew images) boxes to form a cave looking thing, like you're looking into an infinite box that a character will run down and jump around in. The cave however is made up of dozens of boxes that are assigned and on/off randomly when spawned. Drawing from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html which option would be ideal for my situation? The character will move based on the accelerometer tilt and has free movement while the box never changes perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The "options" on that page: using a view layout or a canvas are really options at all.  All drawing in android (aside from OpenGL and other lowlevel 3D rendering) is done on a `Canvas`.

The options here were more about how to specify *what* is drawn on the Canvas.  The first option allows you to specify what is drawn on the canvas using the layout xml.  The second option is about drawing directly on the Canvas during a View's onDraw() method.

For a game with any kind of realistic movement and animation, you'll want to draw directly on the Canvas during the onDraw() event.

You might be able to do some static (layout xml) drawing for menu screens.

Comment: I'm considering a) using a view object or b) drawing to a canvas. Take a look at the link

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a surfaceview most likely, since it can handle custom animation in the easiest manner.

Ideal would be to learn OpenGL and 3D transforms. There is no real thing as 2.5d. What you are probably talking about is a 3D Orthographic Projection. Sometimes this is done with 2d sprites, sometimes it's done with 3d objects.

For capturing the Sensor Information you would use SensorManager in the Android API.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is entirely based on how many separate bitmaps you need to draw and what you would like your frame rate to be. Drawing to the canvas is done via the cpu so it is slower than using Opengl which is hardware accelerated. The canvas actually does an amazing job up to roughly 20-40 20x20px bitmaps. (this is from past experience and is extremely rough).

I would just stick to using the canvas if you can since its simple. It will help you gain a better understanding of what a game loop is and how to design the internals of your game.

Good Luck